# Google Map view with photos layer in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to display the map view in android as such in the google map.But how to get the map with the photos for certain places. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to Implement a [ItemizedOverlay](http://code.google.com/intl/en/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/). See this [code](http://code.google.com/p/ar-droid/source/browse/AR-DROID/src/ar/droid/view/BalloonItemizedOverlay.java?spec=svn226&r=226)  for Overlays like google does it (baloons).